# Find only voice channels name Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can I find every voice channel(name) in guild?

I tried this:

[image: Example code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type 5 is of voice channel you should filter on that which is mention in there [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#channels-resource)

```
let channels=client.channels.cache.filter(ch=>ch.type===2)

channels.map(ch=>console.log(ch))
```